# How to create an adjacency/joint probability matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, adjacency-matrix, probability-density

From a binary matrix, I want to calculate a kind of adjacency/joint probability density matrix (not quite sure how to label it as so please feel free to rename).

For example, I start with this matrix:

```
A = [1   1   0   1   1
     1   0   0   1   1
     0   0   0   1   0]
```

I want to produce this output:

```
Output = [1   4/5   1/5 
         4/5   1    1/5 
         1/5   1/5   1]
```

Basically, for each row, I want to calculate the proportion of times where they agreed (1 and 1 or 0 and 0). A will always agree with itself and thus have it as 1 along the diagonal. No matter how many different js are added it will still result in a 3x3, but an extra i variable will result in a 4x4.

I like to think of the inputs along i in the A matrix as the person and Js as the question and so the final output is a 3x3 (number of persons) matrix.

I am having some trouble with this on matlab. If you could please help point me in the right direction that would be fabulous.

Comment: With your description the expected output should be `[1   4/5   2/5 ; ​4/5   1    3/5 ;2/5   3/5   1] `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can do this in two parts.

```
bothOnes = A*A';
```

gives you a matrix showing how many 1s each pair of rows share, and

```
bothZeros = (1-A)*(1-A)';
```

gives you a matrix showing how many 0s each pair of rows share.

If you just add them up, you get how many elements they share of either type:

```
bothSame = A*A' + (1-A)*(1-A)';
```

Then just divide by the row length to get the desired fractional representation:

```
output = (A*A' + (1-A)*(1-A)') / size(A, 2);
```

That should get you there.

Note that this only works if A contains only 1's and 0's, but it can be adapted for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives, assuming `A` can only contain `0` and `1`:

- If you have the Statistics Toolbox:

  ```
  result = 1-squareform(pdist(A, 'hamming'));
  ```
- Manual approach with implicit expansion:

  ```
  result = mean(permute(A, [1 3 2])==permute(A, [3 1 2]), 3);
  ```
- Using bitwise operations. This is a more esoteric approach, and is only valid if `A` has at most `53` columns, due to floating-point limitations:

  ```
  t = bin2dec(char(A+'0')); % convert each row from binary to decimal
  u = bitxor(t, t.'); % bitwise xor
  v = mean(dec2bin(u)-'0', 2); % compute desired values
  result = 1 - reshape(v, size(A,1), []); % reshape to obtain result
  ```